# Ошибка Cannot convert undefined or null to object. В чем проблема может быть?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Когда я в SELECT выбираю именно определенного юзера, то получаю вот такую ошибку:

```
SiteAdmin.vue?d016:1126 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
    at Function.entries (<anonymous>)
    at Proxy.convertPositions (SiteAdmin.vue?d016:1126)
    at _callee3$ (SiteAdmin.vue?d016:951)
    at tryCatch (runtime.js?96cf:63)
    at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (runtime.js?96cf:293)
    at Generator.eval [as next] (runtime.js?96cf:118)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (asyncToGenerator.js?1da1:3)
    at _next (asyncToGenerator.js?1da1:25)
```

Если посмотреть на нее детальнее, то ошибка говорит, что мы не может взять Product Name у пустого объекта, но я не понимаю почему он пустой.. Все данные приходят нормально, и во vue devtools есть все данные тоже, но когда пытаюсь выбрать этого юзера то ошибка, остальные юзеры отрабатывают.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Вот сам код:
Тут мы делаем запрос.**

```
async handleUsersSelect(userID) {
      console.log("userID", userID);
      const userId = userID || this.$store.state.calculator.users;
      clearInterval(this.timerId);
      this.$store.commit("calculator/setUserSiteAdmin", userId);
      await this.getUserForTable(userId);

      this.timerId = setInterval(async () => {
        this.getUserForTable(userId);
      }, 2000);
    },
```

**Отсюда получаем данные:**

```
async getUserForTable(userId) {
      const marginsResponse = await this.fetchCleintTableInfoByTab({
        userId,
        url: "/admin/margins",
      });
      const positionsResponse = await this.fetchCleintTableInfoByTab({
        userId,
        url: "/admin/positions",
      });
      const dealsResponce = await this.fetchCleintTableInfoByTab({
        userId,
        url: "/admin/deals",
      });
      const ordersResponse = await this.fetchCleintTableInfoByTab({
        userId,
        url: "/admin/orders",
      });
      const fundsResponse = await this.fetchCleintTableInfoByTab({
        userId,
        url: "/admin/funds",
      });
      this.margins = this.convertMargins(marginsResponse);
      this.positions = this.convertPositions(positionsResponse);
      this.deals = this.convertDeals(dealsResponce);
      this.orders = this.convertOrders(ordersResponse);
      this.funds = this.convertFunds(fundsResponse);
      console.log("pos", this.positions);
      console.log("ord", this.orders);
    },
```

**Тут сами поля которые нам приходят с бэкенда:**

```
convertPositions(response) {
      let convertPositions = [];
      const ProductName = Object.entries(response["Product Name"]);
      const Client_Id = Object.entries(response["Client Id"]);
      const Amount = Object.entries(response["Amount"]);
      const Exchange_Position = Object.entries(response["Exchange Position"]);
      const Fin_Result_USD = Object.entries(response["Fin Result USD"]);
      const Fut_Hedge_flag = Object.entries(response["Fut Hedge flag"]);
      const Initial_Price_USD = Object.entries(response["Initial Price USD"]);

      Client_Id.forEach((item, index) => {
        convertPositions.push({});
        convertPositions[index].ProductName = item[1];
      });

      ProductName.forEach((item, index) => {
        convertPositions[index].Client_Id = item[1];
      });

      Amount.forEach((item, index) => {
        convertPositions[index].Amount = item[1];
      });

      Exchange_Position.forEach((item, index) => {
        convertPositions[index].ExchangePosition = item[1];
      });

      Fin_Result_USD.forEach((item, index) => {
        convertPositions[index].FinResultUSD = item[1];
      });

      Fut_Hedge_flag.forEach((item, index) => {
        convertPositions[index].FutHedgeFlag = item[1];
      });

      Initial_Price_USD.forEach((item, index) => {
        convertPositions[index].InitialPriceUSD = item[1];
      });

      return convertPositions;
    },
```

**RESPONCE**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**RESPONCE-PRODUCT-NAME:**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: _Если посмотреть на нее детальнее, то ошибка говорит, что мы не может взять Product Name у пустого объекта_ - нет. Ошибка говорит, что `response["Product Name"]` и есть `undefined`

Comment: Выведи в лог, что находится в `response`

Comment: Добавил responce

Comment: в какой момент вызывается `log`? Выведи его перед `let convertPositions = [];`

Comment: Сделал как вы сказали и обновил фото в вопросе.

Comment: и рядом выведи значение свойства `console.log(response, response["Product Name"])`

Comment: Добавил картинку ниже

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131599/discussion-between-grundy-and-yoz).